# desired output matrix neural network in R

Tags: r, matrix, neural-network

I am working in neural network, `nnet` package in `R`
classifying data belonging to three class, each class has three images.

I have created target matrix by using

`class.ind(c(rep(1,3),rep(2,3),rep(3,3)))`

for three classes (`9*3 matrix`) but the input matrix size is `5700*9(read image column-wise)` so I get an error.

What should be the target matrix if the input matrix is `5700*9`? is the input matrix read correctly? should I make input matrix as a single column?